# Why is the soil between these olive trees left bare?

Tags: soil, agriculture, soil-moisture

These photos were taken this week in the Tarragona province of Spain which is also seeing a heat wave at the moment. One can also see farmers using cultivators removing what were wild weeds that grew in between trees. So it seems to me like a common practice to keep the soil bare (at least this time of the year).

[image]

[image]

My layman understanding is that it is better to not leave soil bare to avoid erosion and evaporation (among other reasons).
What are the benefits of keeping the soil bare?

Answer (score 2):

Bare soil is one of the worst things for erosion. Such soil contains no plant roots to help contain the soil and thus prevent erosion. Bare soil is also one of the worst things for water loss from soil. The parts of plants above the soil can provide shade to the soil, which thus reduces moisture evaporating from the soil. More exposed soil has greater moisture loss and greater chances of being eroded.

As for the soil between the olive trees, the most likely explanation is that the farmer doesn't want anything competing with the olive trees.

Even though weeds will reduce soil moisture loss they also draw soil moisture for themselves so they can live. This places them in direct competition with the olive trees for soil moisture and nutrients.

The farmer derives income from the olive trees and not the weeds. So the farmer removes the weeds, resulting in bare soil between the trees.

The other thing is, when it comes time to harvest the olives, it is easier to harvest them with bare soil than with weeds everywhere.

Comment: it also seems easier and cheaper than planting a cover crop which is the other way to control the weeds. whether it is actually cheaper and easier is a different matter humans often make more work for themselves through laziness.

Comment: It might be also done to reduce the spread of eventual fires.